# Is there a way to search for Top tweets with tweepy instead of latest tweets?

Tags: python, tweepy

It seem tweepy's search function only accesses the latest tweets.  Is there a way to switch it so it searches the top tweets of a given query? Is there a workaround to retrieve the popular tweets if search cannot do this? I'm running OS X and python 3.6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to 

refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Answer (score 2):

Along with your query topic, pass a `result_type='popular'` parameter to tweepy's search function. Although the [tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.search) does not list this in its parameters, it is an available parameter in the [Twitter Dev Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets).

```
popular_tweets = api.search(q='python', result_type='popular') # e.g. "python"
```

> popular : return only the most popular results in the response.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - OP seems to be after list of "most popular" tweets for a given phrase, you have provided a way of finding out the most popular phrases.

Answer (score 2):

This should work (Add your Keys)

```
import tweepy

consumer_key ="" 
consumer_secret =""
access_token =""
access_token_secret =""


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweets = api.search(q='keyword', result_type='popular')
```